# How to use TimeDiff function in Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to use `timediff` function in `where` clause. I need to get scenario value when `timediff(c2,c3) > 30 MIN`

```
SELECT scenario, rowcreatedctime,eventtime FROM `chat_assist_session_request` LIMIT 1 

scenario  rowcreatedtime           eventtime
scen1     2014-09-02 09:00:00      2014-09-02 09:45:00  
scen2     2014-09-02 10:00:00      2014-09-02 10:13:00
```

As per the above data, I need to get `scen1` as output.

Comment: mysql or postgresql? the backticks in your statement indicate mysql, so why is the question tagged with postgresql?

Comment: You have to do it like  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,c1,c2)

Comment: removed the `postgresql` tag as the query is clearly MySQL only (due to the use of the proprietary backticks instead of double quotes)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ... though any MySQL user who hasn't been around since the 3.3 days should be setting `sql_mode = 'ansi'` and using `"proper quoting"` anyway.

Comment: @CraigRinger: you would be surprised how many MySQL user don't even know that there is a "standard way" to do it, and that there is "ANSI" mode as well. And all MySQL tools (e.g. mysqldump) continue to use backticks even in ANSI mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE
time_to_sec(timediff(c1, c2 )) /60 > 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also phrase this without a function on one of the columns by just sing date arithmetic:

```
where c2 <= c1 + interval 30 minute;
```

The advantage of avoiding a function is that MySQL can -- in some circumstances -- take advantage of an index on one of the columns.  Some people might also find it easier to read (oh, does timestamp diff do arg1 - arg2 or arg2 - arg1?).